# StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed' while deleting roles or anyother thing from Skrouba in my API but Post get successful why?

Tags: c#, .net, microservices, identityserver4

StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed' while deleting roles or anyother thing from Skoruba in my API but Post get successful why?

I tried to use http client  GetAsync to get Roles from skourba as follow:

HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Identity");

```
            TokenInfo tokenInfo = await GetTokenAsync();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenInfo.AccessToken);

            var response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}/api/Roles", _configuration.ApiUri));
```

The above code is successful , but whene I try to delete some Role using Following code the code returns 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed' error:

var request = new { roleId = roleId };

```
            var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

            HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Identity");

            TokenInfo tokenInfo = await GetTokenAsync();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenInfo.AccessToken);

            var content = new StringContent(requestBody, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            string identityUri = string.Format("{0}/api/Role/Delete/{1}", _configuration.ApiUri, roleId);

            var response = await client.PostAsync(identityUri, content);

                  OR
var request = new { roleId = roleId };

            var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

            HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Identity");

            TokenInfo tokenInfo = await GetTokenAsync();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenInfo.AccessToken);

            var content = new StringContent(requestBody, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            string identityUri = string.Format("{0}/api/Role/{1}", _configuration.ApiUri, roleId);

            var response = await client.DeleteAsync(identityUri);
```

Comment: It would help if you could share some code. MethodNotAllowed is usually when you sent a GET request a endpoint that only accepts POST, or similar. For a delete method, I would expect it to accept a DELETE

Comment: The results are not successful.  Good results returns 200 OK.  You are using HTTP which does 3 things 1) A Request is sent 2) The server performs processing 3) A result is returned.  It appears the server is doing some processing and then detecting an error.  So you are seeing SOME good results but server is finding an error later in the processing.

Comment: I am using string identityUri = string.Format("{0}/api/roles/{1}", _configuration.ApiUri, roleId); var response = await client.DeleteAsync(identityUri); where _configuration.ApiUri, = {myApiUrl}/identity/adminapi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.